# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND styles.css

Tags: html, css, github

I have a problem, when I open the index.html with liveserver I load the styles.css but when I uploaded my page to github does not load me or styles.css and some images either, I looked 1 million times if the url was well written and everything is fine, if someone could help me would be grateful
[image: the consolevisual studio]

Check the path and I can't find the error

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure not to write complete path of your CSS file (`C:/User/abc/.../styles.css`) instead write path from it's working directory (`../css/styles.css`) and also if it doesn't help then kindly share some of your code so I can see and help you more.

Comment: You can show some code where you are attaching your CSS files and also do not post them as an answer instead reply to this comment and lets talk here.